# How do I download and edit files in a Chrome app/extension?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The build process for my CSS take a really long time. I want to make an extension that lets me edit my stylesheets in the browser and persist them. It will show the diff between the edited version and the original version. I can copy the diff and apply them to my source CSS (Sass).

I think I will have to download the CSS, let the user modify it in their editor of choice, and redirect requests for the original CSS to the modified CSS. I got the CSS to save using `chrome.downloads.download`, but it's saved in the downloads folder. I don't think the extension can access the downloads folder. One way is to have the user manually save the file in the extension folder, but that's too troublesome.

Is there a way to let the Chrome extension show the edited version of a file?

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or invites discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: you will likely need to store in chrome storage, not filesystem, then somehow inject it into the page.